# uwsgi in docker in vagrant in vmware - socket not being created

Tags: docker, nginx, vagrant, vmware, uwsgi

On my mac I am running Windows Server 2016 in VMware. In there I am running Ubuntu in vagrant/Virtual Box. In there I am trying to run a django app in a docker container with nginx/uwsgi.

uwsgi is failing to start with:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /opt/django/CAPgraph/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Thu Aug 17 20:01:23 2017] ***
compiled with version: 6.4.0 20170805 on 17 August 2017 06:10:50
os: Linux-3.13.0-128-generic #177-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 11:40:23 UTC 2017
nodename: 37db4344b5ae
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
chdir() to /opt/django/CAPgraph/
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Operation not permitted [core/socket.c line 230]
```

In VMware the folder is set for sharing for everyone with write permission. That is mounted in the vagrant VM where it is 777, and in the docker container is it also 777. I can create files in the dir from all 3 places. But it seems uwsgi cannot create the socket.

I tried a short python script as a test from vagrant and that could not create a socket either:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/vagrant/app.sock')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

UPDATE: I changed the dir to /tmp where I can create a socket with my python script, but still uwsgi fails with the same error.

UPDATE 2: I created the socket in /tmp with my python script, chmod-ed it to 777 and still I get the same error from uwsgi.

Comment: The problem is that `/vagrant` is not same as a normal folder. If execute the command `mount | grep vagrant` you will find it uses a `vboxfs` file system and it doesn't gel well with docker

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Use any other folder other than `/vagrant`. I usually use `/home/vagrant`

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick!

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon. The socket be being created, but then when I try and connect to the site it fails with this nginx error: `2017/08/19 16:56:29 [crit] 1251#1251: *1 connect() to unix:///opt/django/CAPgraph/app.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///opt/django/CAPgraph/app.sock:", host: "localhost:9003"` I have verified that the app.sock file and all dirs along the path are 777.

Comment: I changed the socket to be in /var/run and that fixed the issue. But now I am getting a 403 on all the static files, e.g:

`2017/08/20 13:42:37 [error] 1140#1140: *8 open() "/opt/django/CAPgraph/static/scripts/bootstrap.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.2.2, server: , request: "GET /static/scripts/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:9003", referrer: "http://localhost:9003/"`

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Change the owner for `/opt/django/CAPgraph/` recursively to `www-data` or `nginx` depending on which user is being used for your webserver

Comment: That did not fix it. However I found that copying the static files to /var/run (and changing the nginx config) did fix it.

Comment: That may mean a path issue in config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any other folder other than `/vagrant`. I usually use /home/vagrant

The problem is that `/vagrant` is not same as a normal folder. If you execute the command `mount | grep vagrant` you will find it uses a `vboxfs` file system, which for some reason doesn't gel well with docker